# List custom posts

Tags: custom-post-types

I want list  all the upcoming and past events(custom posts) in chronological order.
I have saved data by meta key start_time,duration ,

I try to use sql ,but can not get there!

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: How is your date meta stored (what format)? If it is a Unix timestamp, you could set the `orderby` parameter of your query to `meta_value_num`.

Comment: time stamp,well I try this: `SELECT  (SELECT ABS(m1.meta_value-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())) from wp_postmeta AS m1 WHERE m1.meta_key='st_time' AND m1.post_id=p.ID) AS dis 
    FROM wp_posts AS p, wp_postmeta AS m
    WHERE p.ID = m.post_id 
     ORDER BY  dis`,the query_post() may not have so much!

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `WP_Query` instead of using the `SQL`. You can get the reference [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Simple example would be like:

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'my_custom_post_type',
   'meta_key' => 'date',
   'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
   'order' => 'ASC',
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'event_date',
           'value' => date()
       )
   )
 );
 $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

and use a simple `while` loop to iterate through the results.

See [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) for more info on meta query parameters.

Comment: Well,I know this useful WP_Query,but the main point is I want to sort by the difference between meta_value and another object(like now time)!